# leet code calculator II code

Tags: java

This is a problem that is asked on leet code for a simple calculator. The problem is stated as follows -

Implement a basic calculator to evaluate a simple expression string.

The expression string contains only non-negative integers, +, -, *, / operators and empty spaces . The integer division should truncate toward zero.

Example 1:

```
Input: "3+2*2"
Output: 7
```

Example 2:

```
Input: " 3/2 "
Output: 1
```

Example 3:

```
Input: " 3+5 / 2 "
Output: 5
```

Note:
You may assume that the given expression is always valid.
Do not use the eval built-in library function.

This is the code I wrote in a short span of time, I did not design it for more complicated cases -

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class Solution{
    
    Stack<Integer> numberStack = new Stack();
    Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack();
    
    //assuming op1 is in operator stack and op2 is to be inserted
    public boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2){
        if (op2 == '/' && op1 != '/'){
            return true;
        }
        
        if (op2 == '*' && (op1 == '+' || op1 == '-')){
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    // -1 means invalid
    //  0 means number
    //  1 means an operator
    public int validate(char operand){
        boolean isNumber = false;
        if (Character.isDigit(operand)){
            isNumber = true; 
        }
        boolean isOperator = false;
        if (operand != '/' || operand !='*' || operand !='+' || operand != '-'){
            isOperator = true;
        }
        
        if (!(isNumber || isOperator)){
            return -1;
        }
        
        if (isNumber){
            return 0;
        }
        
        if (isOperator){
            return 1;
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    private void performOperation(){
        if(operatorStack.empty() || numberStack.empty()){
            return;
        }
        char operator = operatorStack.pop();
        if(numberStack.size() < 2){
            return;
        }
        int num2 = numberStack.pop();
        int num1 = numberStack.pop();
        int result = 0;
        switch(operator){
            case '/': result = num1/num2;
                      numberStack.push(result);
                      break;
            case '+': result = num1+num2;
                      numberStack.push(result);
                      break;
            case '*': result = num1*num2;
                      numberStack.push(result);
                      break;
            case '-': result = num1-num2;
                      numberStack.push(result);
                      break;
        }         
            
    }
            
    private int calculate(String exp) throws Exception{
        
        if (exp == null || exp.trim().length() == 0 ){
            throw new Exception("Null or empty expression ");
        }
        char[] operArray = exp.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer numberBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        
        
        char operand = '\0';
        for (int i=0; i < operArray.length ; i++){
            operand = operArray[i];
            if (Character.isWhitespace(operand)){
                continue;
            }
            int opVal = -1;
            opVal = validate(operand);
            if (opVal == -1){
                throw new Exception("Invalid inputs ");
            }
            
            //current char is number
            if (opVal == 0){
                numberBuffer.append(operand);
                continue;
            }
            
            if (opVal == 1){
                numberStack.push(Integer.parseInt(numberBuffer.toString()));
                numberBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            
                if (!operatorStack.empty()){
                    if(!hasPrecedence(operatorStack.peek(), operand)){
                        performOperation();
                    }
                }
                    operatorStack.push(operand);
            }
        }
        
        numberStack.push(Integer.parseInt(numberBuffer.toString()));
        while(!operatorStack.isEmpty()){
            performOperation();
        }
        return numberStack.pop();
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
        Solution expparser = new Solution();
        int result = expparser.calculate("3+2*2");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate(" 3/2 ");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate(" 3+5 / 2 ");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate("3+2-2");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate(" 3/2-1 ");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate(" 3/5/2 ");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate("3/5*2");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate("3*5*2");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
        result = expparser.calculate(" 3+5+2 ");
        System.out.println("result is " + result);
    }
}
```

Considering there are no negative numbers in the expression, this code works fine and the test cases have all passed. How can I improve this code?

Comment: Please take a look at GNU Coreutils "expr" program for an example of how to implement an infix calculator. It can be implemented very neatly using recursion. https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/expr.c

Answer (score 5):

### Consider using the `Deque` instead of the `Stack`

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html), the use of the `Deque` is preferred. You can have more information on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524949/12511456).

### Replace the `for` loop with an enhanced 'for' loop

In your code, you don’t actually need the index provided by the loop, you can the enhanced version.

**Before**

```java
for (int i = 0; i < operArray.length; i++) {
   //[...]
}
```

**After**

```java
for (char c : operArray) {
   //[...]
}
```

### Simplify the boolean conditions.

Generally, when you are returning both `true` and `false` surrounded by a condition, you know you can refactor the logic of the expression.

**Before**

```java
if (op2 == '*' && (op1 == '+' || op1 == '-')) {
   return true;
}

return false;
```

**After**

```java
return op2 == '*' && (op1 == '+' || op1 == '-');
```

### `Solution#validate` method

1. I suggest that you extract the logic to check if the number is an operator / number is two separate methods; this will make the code shorter and easier to read.
2. The logic can be simplified, you can remove the `!(isNumber || isOperator)` and if neither, the method will return `-1`.
3. The `operand != '/' || operand !='*' || operand !='+' || operand != '-'` is flawed; will always return true.

```java
// -1 means invalid
//  0 means number
//  1 means an operator
public int validate(char operand) {
   boolean isNumber = isNumber(operand);
   boolean isOperator = isOperator(operand);

   if (isNumber) {
      return 0;
   } else if (isOperator) {
      return 1;
   }

   return -1;
}

private boolean isNumber(char operand) {
   return Character.isDigit(operand);
}

private boolean isOperator(char operand) {
   return operand == '/' || operand == '*' || operand == '+' || operand == '-';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One additional remark on `validate()`.

You have three output cases:

- invalid
- number
- operator

Instead of encoding them as integers (which is not a natural natural choice, as you can't meaningfully add, subtract or multiply them), I'd introduce an enum:

```
enum Validation { INVALID, NUMBER, OPERATOR }
```

Then the `validate()` method reads

```
public Validation validate(char operand) {
    ...
}
```

Hint: whenever you feel it necessary to explain the meaning of some numbers, consider introducing an enum instead. You get a lot of benefits without any significant downsides.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have considered to use only one stack ?

You can wrap your numbers into a constant entry that returns the number. And create one operation entry for each valid operation. So that you can "just" reduce your stack until she has one item.

```
Stack<Function<Integer, Integer>> operations = new Stack<>();


public Integer resolve(final Integer x) {
    Integer right = x;
    while ( !operations.isEmpty() ) {
        right = operations.pop().apply(right);
    }
    return right;
}
```